# Hide/Show A Div After A Few Seconds

Tags: jquery, settimeout

I have a Div. I would like to hide it after 10 seconds then show it after 30 seconds then hide it again after 10sec and so on.

I have this code but it doesn't work the way I had imagined it.

```
setTimeout(function() { 
    $("#myDiv").hide(); 
    setTimeout(function() {     
            $("#myDiv").show(); 
    },30000);
},10000);
```

Any advice?

Comment: did you check the id of your div?

Comment: You should read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729921/settimeout-or-setinterval

Comment: I have added an alternate answer below for you, which looks pretty cool (uses the `timing` library) so your code becomes: `$("#myDiv").repeat().wait(10000).show().wait(30000).hide();` which I find far more readable. Recommend looking at that lib :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just loop it like

```
function toggleDiv() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#myDiv").hide();
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#myDiv").show();
            toggleDiv();
        }, 30000);
    }, 10000);
}
toggleDiv();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Y3mS4/)

Comment: I saw your fiddle Arun, I'm just learning Javascript now, why should we use `toggleDiv();` when it works without calling this function

Comment: @user3004356: `toggleDiv` is just the code itself. This is calling the function recursively. If you do not call it in this example it will only run once. Only setInterval calls a function repeatedly.

Comment: perfect! i have not thought about using a recursive function. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `setInterval` like,

```
setInterval(function() { 
    $("#myDiv").hide(); 
    setTimeout(function() {     
        $("#myDiv").show(); 
    },10000);
},30000);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/zDV6F/)

You can set time accordingly like for your problem try,

```
setInterval(function() { 
    $("#myDiv").hide(); 
    setTimeout(function() {     
       $("#myDiv").show(); 
    },3000);
},4000);
```

[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/zDV6F/2/)

Comment: the interval will get called every 10 secs... where it takes 40 secs to complete a cycle

Comment: Now the timing does not match the requirements... Hide after 10 seconds (not 30). This shows after 10 seconds then hides after 30.

Comment: I have added an answer which includes *what you intended to do* with `setInterval` (assuming an initial show state was allowed), as well as a better alternative using the `timing` library.

Answer (score 1):

Use setInterval(func, timeout)  instead, it will run every timeout milliseconds and in the func toggle div between visible and hidden

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the initial state being "shown", you can do this (which is what Rohan Kumar probably intended):

```
setInterval(function() { 
    $("#myDiv").show(); 
    setTimeout(function() {     
       $("#myDiv").hide(); 
    },10000);
},40000);
```

The repeat timer is set to every 40 seconds (the total interval of 30+10) and the hide occurs after a fixed timeout of 10 seconds.

There is also a `timing` library that extends JQuery animation (to allow for repeats etc):

### http://creativecouple.github.com/jquery-timing/

Then your code becomes something like:

```
$("#myDiv").repeat().wait(10000).show().wait(30000).hide();
```

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/zDV6F/1/

Which I think is pretty cool.

*If you don't mind the extra calls, or don't want an extra libary, go with Arun P Johny's answer.*